# R shiny SQL database - reactive filtering - best practice?

Tags: sql, r, dbi, shiny-reactivity

New to R shiny and SQL
I have made some reactive dashboards but none yet using SQL database connection.

Here is my toy:
The database is the MySQL world database.
I want to join various tables and show some columns from each, but I want to be able to filter by Language found in the CountryLanguage table.

My WHERE statement doesn't work.

Current code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("nrows", "Enter the number of rows to display:", 5),
  
selectizeInput("inputlang", label = "Language", choices = NULL, selected = NULL, options = list(placeholder = "Please type a language")),
  
tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    conn <- dbConnect(
      drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
      dbname = "shinydemo",
      host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      username = "guest",
      password = "guest")
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
   
dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(
      "SELECT City.Name, City.Population, Country.Name, Country.Continent, CountryLanguage.Language, CountryLanguage.Percentage
      FROM City 
      INNER JOIN Country on City.CountryCode = Country.Code
      INNER JOIN CountryLanguage on Country.Code = CountryLanguage.CountryCode
      WHERE CountryLanguage.Language = reactive({get(input$Selectize)})
      LIMIT ", input$nrows, ";"))


  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I did not expect that code to work, but tried anyway.  I suspect I can't pass an R command from within a dbGetQuery because it is expecting SQL syntax only. Is that correct?

So... what is the best way to set something like this up? I imagine I could make the joined selected stuff into a dataframe like

```
    df <-dbGetQuery ( SELECT & JOIN)

    dffilter <- df %>% filter ()
```

But is that going to make things super slow if the dataset is still quite large?

What would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Having `reactive(...)` in a string is not evaluated, it's just a string. Further, `DBI` is not using `glue` on the query, so `{get(...)}` will do nothing.
2. You define the input as `input$inputlang` but in your reactive, you reference `input$Selectize`, I think that's a mistake.
3. You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), either natively or via add-ons.

   While this does not work for the `LIMIT` portion, it is useful for most other portions of a query. For that `limit` part, the `req(is.numeric(input$nrows))` should be a reasonable check to ensure inadvertent injection problems.

Try this:

```r
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    req(is.numeric(input$nrows), input$inputlang)
    conn <- dbConnect(
      drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
      dbname = "shinydemo",
      host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      username = "guest",
      password = "guest")
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    
    dbGetQuery(conn, paste("
      SELECT City.Name, City.Population, Country.Name, Country.Continent, CountryLanguage.Language, CountryLanguage.Percentage
      FROM City 
      INNER JOIN Country on City.CountryCode = Country.Code
      INNER JOIN CountryLanguage on Country.Code = CountryLanguage.CountryCode
      WHERE CountryLanguage.Language = ?
      LIMIT ", input$nrows),
      params = list(input$inputlang))

  })
```

Comment: Thanks- you're right re #2- I changed the name to be inputlang so it more descriptive and was sloppy about it.

Comment: I tried the above code but I don't seem to get any table.  I get the table as expected if I leave out the WHERE statement but I'm still stuck on that.

Comment: Have you tried a manual query (not within shiny) to confirm that the languages you expect are actually found? It's difficult to troubleshoot not knowing what is in the database nor what you (or the user) are (is) typing in.

Comment: If I run the code with no filter on language the table I get shows the language - the first on the list is Balochi so I've been entering that into my selectize with no success,

Comment: I also tried changing my selectize to just a select and putting in a few languages as options including Balochi and when I do that I get the error message: unused argument (params = list("Balochi"))

Comment: I think part of my problem is I'm a scientist without any proper background in programming and trying to learn by modifying examples without strong base understanding, so I appreciate your patience if my questions or problems appear stupid.

Comment: In other dashboards that connected to csv files, I would have before the ui part had some code like: allusers <- sort(unique(pwc$user.name)) and then in the selectInput had choices= allusers in the ui.  I don't know how to replicate that when I connect to the db in the ui and use SQL syntax over the whole connection.

Comment: Let me restate my previous suggestion: run the SQL query manually and determine if the problem is with `shiny`, `DBI`, or perhaps spelling or *case*. For example, SQL Server thinks that `'a'='A'` (sqlserver cherry-picks standards and intuition, imo), neither PostgreSQL nor SQLite do. SQLite accepts `'a' like 'A'`, and PostgreSQL needs `'a' ilike 'A'`, where 'like' by itself does not work. So ... try your query outside of shiny, using a `where` clause for the language, just as you have tested typing into your shiny interface.